# Pasting in Putty causes freeze

Tags: windows-8.1, copy-paste, putty

I need to paste a lot of code lines into Putty on Windows (8.1). So I know how copy/pasting works but from the moment I try to paste more than 30 something characters, it causes to program to freeze and I can't type/press enter/etc. But the pasting DOES work because when I paste only a few words it does this without problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wow, this is 3 years old. I encountered the same with PuttyTray on Windows 10. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I believe I did, however I don't even remember why I needed to use Putty, so I'm not sure if I can help you. It was probably for a school assignment but I forgot which one, I'll try to find it.

Comment: did the same problem at 2019 august.

Answer (score 0):

https://etherealmind.com/putty-recomend-default-settings-network-engineer/?doing_wp_cron=1588819245.8040070533752441406250&fbclid=IwAR3VQBVKL98654SKDqv3deSnlAMzR1D3UFbI2DOwgqTzydNMx5eN1YgPk-Y

Try this out: go to "Connection" catagoty and then uncheck "disable Nagle's algorithm..."

Nagles Algorithm
Nagle’s algorithm is particularly useful when attempting to transfer a lot of information in the terminal. For example, when logging at high speed or pasting large configurations to your console (there are many other criteria that affect this, but this is one of them).